# Is there a limitation of how much code can be inserted into Excel or is it a bug?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel spreadsheet that is indefinitely code heavy, but only in Excel coding, not VBA, 90% of all text has code one form or another wrapped in it, around it or is created by it.

Is there a limitation of how much code can be written into a page before it starts to show itself as "normal text" even though it has a "=" before it?

`=IF(ROW($AI1)>$AJ$2, "", INDEX(AB$4:AB$23, SMALL(IF(AA$4:AA$23=Criteria, ROW($AA$4:$AA$23), ""), ROW($AI1))))`

That is the code, it shows up as text even though the field is shown as "General" for it's formatting, now mind you I have over 400 fields integrated with code itself. It is pretty much a calendar, and soon to be one that updates specific fields on a daily basis upon starting the sheet up. Or so it my hope.

But when I enter the code above, the sheet doesn't accept it as code, but as text so the entire script is shown, instead of the field with the data it is meant to show instead.

Is this a bug in Microsoft Excel, or is there an actual limitation of what Excel can handle per sheet for code? I can't imagine I found it, because this sheet is far from complete, and I've seen more complex ones out there...

Comment: Is it just that cell or all the cells on your worksheet? If you just edit it and press enter, does it make a difference?

Comment: If your formatting is general on the sheet, you are not in formula mode (CTRL+`) and revalidating the formula does not make a difference... I am out of ideas! I have just copied your formula to 100,000 cells in Excel 2010 and it works fine.

Comment: Just tried the same in Excel 2003: no problem. Are you sure you don't have a space before the `=`?

Comment: Must be my computer, joy... my work refuses to buy a new computer, well it looks like I may have a reason to get one now.

Comment: Are the cells formatted as Text?  If they are, a valid formula displays as text and is not evaluated.  You need to change the format to General and edit the cell get the formula evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pressing Control+Accent Grave (Cntl+`).  If you're in formula view mode, you'll see formulas instead of values.

Comment: Already tried that, first time and it comes back showing the formula, and not what was expected, otherwise I'd be on my merry way I'd not of asked in the first place :)

Comment: Like assylias I'm stumped.  If you think it might be a corrupted workbook, make a backup of the file, save the file as html, open it and resave it in Excel format.  Roundtripping through html can fix some stuff.

Comment: It may be or it just may be my computer, because it works at home fine.